# Rails 5 controller before_action method not receiving form params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, form-helpers

I have an application that has a Venue model, each venue has many events, and each event has many sign_ups as signupable (I have another model that has sign ups as well). My issue is when I am trying to create a sign up for a specific event from the venue page. Here is my relevant code:

Models:

```
# app/models/venue.rb
class Venue < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
end


# app/models/event.rb
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :venue
  has_many :sign_ups, as: :signupable
end


# app/models/sign_up.rb
class SignUp < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :signupable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Controllers:

```
 #app/controllers.sign_ups_controller.rb

 class SignUpsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_signupable

    def new
      @sign_up = SignUp.new
    end

    def create
      @sign_up = @signupable.sign_ups.new sign_up_params

      if @sign_up.save
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:notice] = 'Your submission was received!'
      else
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:danger] = "Error: #{@sign_up.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}"
      end
    end

    private

    def sign_up_params
      params.require(:sign_up).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, :num_guys, :num_girls, :date)
    end

    def find_signupable
      @signupable = Event.find(params[:event_id]) if params[:event_id]
      @signupable = Event.find(params[:event]) if params[:event]
    end
end
```

Form:

```
# app/views/venues/_sign_up_form.html.html

= form_for [@venue, SignUp.new] do |f|
  .form-group
    %label{ :for => "event" } Event ID
    = f.select :event, options_from_collection_for_select(@venue.events, :id, :name), {:prompt => "Select Date"}, {class: "form-control", id: "event"}
  .form-group
    = f.submit "Submit", class: "form-control"
```

When I try to submit the form I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError at /venues/20/sign_ups
undefined method `sign_ups' for nil:NilClass
```

I am pretty new to rails and not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm guessing `find_signupable` isn't getting `params[:event]`.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters from your form will like below:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"(snip)", "sign_up"=>{"event"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "venue_id"=>"1"}
```

As you said, `find_signupable` isn't getting `params[:event]`. So the id of a Event is in `params[:sign_up][:event]`. This will be find the Event correctly:

```
def find_signupable
  # If you use Ruby 2.3 or above, you may do params.dig(:sign_up, :event) instead of this:
  event_id = params[:sign_up] && params[:sign_up][:event]

  @signupable = Event.find(event_id) if event_id
end
```

(Note 1) Note that as your example uses `@venue` in the template, it has to be defined in the `new` action like this:

```
@venue = Venue.find(params[:venue_id])
```

(Note 2) Additionally, your `f.select :event` in the template will raise a NoMethodError since the SignUp model doesn't have `event`. So I think that you have to change it to `f.select :signupable_id` and change `find_signupable` method in the controller to like below:

```
def find_signupable
  # If you use Ruby 2.3 or above, you may do params.dig(:sign_up, :signupable_id) instead of this:
  signupable_id = params[:sign_up] && params[:sign_up][:signupable_id]

  @signupable = Event.find(signupable_id) if signupable_id
end
```